# BibLaTeX overflowing URL

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, urls

When using biblatex with a long URL without many forward slashes the URL overflows outside of the margins of the page.

For example:

references.bib

```
@online{ons,
    author = "Office for National Statistics",
    title = "Overview of the UK population: July 2017",
    url = {https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/articles/overviewoftheukpopulation/july2017},
    year = "2017"
}
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[style=ieee,citestyle=ieee,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
    Lots of text
    ...
    \cite{ons}
    \newpage
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Produces the following result:
[image]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  There are lots of other questions about this problem.  [This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134191) may contain some useful information.

Comment: Note that you should be wrapping so-called corporate authors like `Office for National Statistics` in an additional pair of braces (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864): `author = {{Office for National Statistics}},`. You should also protect `UK` and `July` in the `title` from unwanted case change: `title  = {Overview of the {UK} population: {July} 2017},` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10772/35864).

Comment: There are also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22854/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30857/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three suggestions:

- Load the `xurl` package. It allows line breaks in URL strings at arbitrary positions.
- Encase the `author` field in an extra pair of curly braces, so that biber/bibtex doesn't misinterpret the name as consisting of first name component "Office", von component "for", and surname component "National Statistics". Observe that in the screenshot you posted, the "first name component" got truncated to its initial, "O.". Not good!
- Encase the word `UK` in a pair of curly braces, to keep it from getting lowercased. Again, look at the screenshot you posted: The word "UK" got rendered as "uk". Not good!

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@online{ons,
    author = "{Office for National Statistics}",
    title = "Overview of the {UK} population: July 2017",
    url = {https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/populationandmigration/populationestimates/articles/overviewoftheukpopulation/july2017},
    year = "2017"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,citestyle=ieee,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document}
    \cite{ons}
    \newpage
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: An additional comment: I believe that the BibTeX style file `IEEEtran.bst` typesets URL strings using the basic ("roman") text font, not in a monospaced font as is shown in the screenshot above. If you need to copy the `IEEEtran` settings, simply add the instruction `\urlstyle{same}` after loading the `xurl` package.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the package *url* package.

[See this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/672585/160920)

The difference between xurl and url you can [find in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430789/160920)

(short: the package *xurl* loads the package *url* and adds some capabilities)

Comment: `biblatex` already loads the `url` package, so you don't need to load it explicitly unless you need to pass options to it. `biblatex` already extends `url`'s capabilities a bit to allow finer control over breaks (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22854/35864).