# URL in bibliography leaves defined textarea

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex`, however some URLs exceed the textwidth, i.e. they enter the margin. What is the easiest way to handle this problem?

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example shwat  shows this probloem such that others can easily test your problem and provide suggestions. As your question stands we have not idea which preamble you use or which document class.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134191/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22854/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/484176/35864 (and for a more general overview https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864)